# EXEC sproc returns no results if parameters are declared separately

Tags: sql-server

I am puzzled as to why this returns results:

```
EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation = N'GetAllPhotoIDs', @TicketID = 1
```

but this does not:

```
DECLARE @Operation AS nvarchar(29) = N'GetAllPhotoIDs',
        @TicketID AS int = 1

EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation, @TicketID
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: **EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @TicketID, @Operation** did not work as there more parameters between Operation and TicketID (error: Error converting data type nvarchar to int); **GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation = @Operation, @TicketID = @TicketID** does not return anything like the original call

Comment: Can we see the code of your sp?

Comment: and the error message please

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk I don't think that there is an error message, the question mentions that the first query return results and the second doesn't

Comment: Your second version bind parameters on position instead of Name. If your SP has defined the parameters with `@TicketID` first (and @TicketID is a string) you could get what you see. Try to reverse the parameters `EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @TicketID, @Operation` or bind by name `EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation = @Operation, @TicketID = @TicketID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation, @TicketID
```

is the same thing as typing

```
EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments N'GetAllPhotoIDs', 1
```

in your example.  As Mikael mentions in the comments above, parameters are binding by position, not name.

Use

```
EXEC GTKT_SP_Attachments @Operation = @Operation, @TicketID = @TicketID
```